# background image in span element is overlapping another element background image

Tags: css

background image in span element is overlapping another element background image

```
background-color: inherit;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

i already give these two properties for prevent issue. but sometimes issues came in my web page.

```
.iconImage {
background-image: url(images/svg/S_TL_CATALOG.svg);
margin-left: -18px;
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
width: 36px;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
background-color: inherit;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

help me to solve this issue.thanks

```
<div> // listed images for tools icon
   <span></span> //background image1 .. this is static image
   <span></span> //background image2 ..  coming images are dynamically adding images by drag and drop 
   ---------
</div>
```

this is my html format.
after refresh my webpage background image2 loading first then background image1 loading next image2 is overlapping the image1.

mouseover on the two images at that time also overlapping. anything css properties is there for solve this

Comment: paste your full code

Comment: Could you also include your HTML? Thanks

Comment: pls consider to add more code example to your question

Comment: pls check my html format

Comment: its depend on image size and net speed

Comment: mouseover on the two images at that time also overlapping. anything css properties is there for solve this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would help if u post a more detailed code.

Maybe it’s a display problem..
Try to change the display value:

```
display: block;
```

If u want to display the span block ements next to each other, add

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-blend-mode: screen;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

give this css property to element